# I have some file in Azure blob,how can I get that xml file and convert it into json and the result to be pushed into blob again using C#

Tags: c#

I have some file in Azure blob,how can I get that xml file and convert it into json and the result to be pushed into blob again using C#.I have a code to convert xml to json using visual studio.Please anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to retrieve the blob. XML can do a lot that JSON can't, but if your XML is relatively simple, you can convert it with JSON.NET...

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class ConvertXmlToJson
{
    public string XmlToJson(string xml)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xdoc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! I need help to retrieve data from blob and push that to blob. how can I do that?

Comment: It's well documented and only a few lines of code. See Microsoft [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-dotnet-quickstart). If you're still having trouble, open a new question.